# Laravel 8 - define relationships dynamically

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I'm trying to build out functionality to allow users to comment on different types of data.  Blog posts, videos, images, documents, comments (reply to), etc.  So each of those is going to need to define a relationship to the Comments model.  So basically

```
public function comments()
{
  return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->whereNull('parent_id');
}
```

Aside: (parent_id) is in there to allow for replying to comments.

Anyway, to reduce code duplication I can just create a Trait called, say, **CommentsTrait** which has the method above and just use it by the relevant models.  Easy-peasy.  The problem, though, is that in the **Comment** class I am going to have to hard code a method to define the relationship to blog posts, videos, images, documents, etc.  So basically if I wanted another model to use comments, I would need to import the trait into that model and also add a method to **Comment** setting up the relationship.  Not *necessarily* a bad thing but I would like to make that process a bit more dynamic.  That way I can turn comments on/off only from the model using the trait (by including it or not) and that's that.

So is there a way to make it so the **Comment** model can dynamically determine (either internally or externally, say using a provider) which models are using the trait and set up the relationship that way?

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: the inverse relationship would be on `Comment` named `commentable` and would just be `$this->morphTo()` ... it knows the type of relationship it is by the `commentable_type` field of the table ... so you only need 1 method on `Comment` to get any of what its morphed to ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-model-structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one relationship method on `Comment` that would return what ever it belongs to. There should be a `commentable_id` and a `commentable_type` field on the `comments` table. The `morphTo` relationship would know what model it belongs to from the `commentable_type` field. You should only need this method on `Comment`:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Polymorphic Relationships - One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) `morphTo`

Comment: I saw that section but I guess I misunderstood exactly what it was saying.  Your penultimate sentence is what I think I needed to make it click.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic relationships are included in this way.

```
    Comment::resolveRelationUsing ('video', function ($commentModel) {

         return $commentModel->belongsTo(Video::class, 'commentable_id')
                             ->where('commentable_type', Video::class);
           //or simple 
           $commentModel->morphTo()->where(/*... */); // your custom logic
    });
```

You can place this in boot traits or in the service provider with your own conditions and logic.

Comment: Thank you for your input.   I appreciate your time.  However, as I mentioned in my OP, I was trying to avoid having to add code specifically for each new content type (model) I add commenting functionality to.